# How to call logic inside of a setter?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a property that has a Setter with a logic inside it (to generate random string for an Id).

```
public class Customer
{
  private string _customerId;

  public string  CustomerId
  {
      get { return _customerId; }
      private set { _customerId = Utilities.RandomString(6); }
  }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

But how can I call this property from another class, to actually trigger the logic inside the Setter?

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] arg)
  {
    var customer = new Customer();
    customer.CustomerName = "John";
    customer.CustomerId = ?????
  }
}
```

Or am I over-complicating things and should not use this logic inside this property?

Comment: Over-complicated and potentially confusing. Remove the setter. A setter is essentially a method that takes a parameter, one which you don't intend to use. Instead, provide a `GenerateCustomerId` method that takes *no* parameters.

Comment: Could you just set `_customerId` in the constructor and remove the setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alexander Goldabin said, the constructor would be a better place for this logic, *if* the goal is that the customer ID is always randomly generated. There are situations where it makes sense to have logic in a setter, but generating an initial value is better suited for a constructor.

Additionally, I would keep the setter private if the calling code should not be able to update the randomly-generated value:

```
public class Customer
{
  public Customer()
  {
    CustomerId = Utilities.RandomString(6);
  }

  public string CustomerId { get; }

  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

(Note that the constructor is allowed to modify the getter-only property, but nothing else can.)

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Goldabin!

Comment: Thank you @Nate Barbettini !

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `private` modifier from the setter to be able to set values for that property from the outside of the Customer class.

But, looking at your code, it seems that you don't need that logic in setter. Instead you could assign random customer ID in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your property setter is declared as `private`, so you won't be able to assign to it from another class. Remove the `private` accessor from the property, then you could assign any value you wish to really, since you're not using `value` inside the setter. So like the following:

```
customer.CustomerId = "any-string-here";
```

That being said, I don't believe this is the best way to achieve the required outcome. A potential alternative method, is to generate the random ID when the value of the property is retrieved for the first time. You can then do away with the setter entirely. A proposed solution:

```
public class Customer
{
  private string _customerId;

  public string  CustomerId
  {
      get
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_customerId))
            _customerId = Utilities.RandomString(6);

        return _customerId;
      }
  }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is not correct if the setter is _private_ You cannot set that value outside the class

Comment: Very true, I missed that originally. Have amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: the `get` in your example would apply the `RandomString` even on the existing customers without Ids, while the OP needs only to be applied on new customers.

Comment: @iSR5 I don't see that explicitly mentioned in the question. My answer is based on the OPs implementation - `RandomString` would always be assigned to the value of `_customerId`, whether it's an existing customer or new, since the setter doesn't use `value`. Based on that behavior, I provided the above solution. Granted, looking at the other provided answers, this functionality may be better suited to the constructor.